# Separating rows containing values

Tags: r, split, dataframe

So I have a huge data set of over 500,000 different rows I need to separate. Each row is a set of numbers such as this:

```
P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000
```

The important thing to note here is the "`P04012`" section which corresponds to one specific table. A few hundred thousand items down, the code transforms into this:

```
P051120150000000000000002158101110000000210000184380
```

With "`P05112015`" meaning something different. The first 8-10 characters for each string of numbers corresponds to a certain table, but as of right now they are all lumped into one huge dataset with one column and 500,000 rows. How do I separate the rows into the specific tables based on their numbers?

I plan to use `read.fwf` to split the number strings into columns, so really at this point it is simply figuring out how to split them into tables.

Comment: This question is hard for me to understand.  Do you just want to extract the first 8-10 characters from each row?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Okay, so here is a section of the huge data file:

P040120000000000000000004212992540000021300000000000
P040120000000000000000004212992650000000730000000000
P050120010000000000000004112991110000021570000000000
P050120010000000000000004112991120000001110000000000

What I need to do is separate the number strings containing "P04012" from everything else basically. These strings are like number 60,000 in the dataset, so there are roughly 60,000 entries with "p04012" in the first six spaces and the rest is changed after that. Does this clarify the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility that might work for you which uses `read.fwf()`:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)

# fake data file
tf <- tempfile()
x <- cat(
  "P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000",
  "P051120150000000000000002158101110000000210000184380",
  sep = "\n",
  file = tf)

# get table identifiers using read.fwf()
ids <- read.fwf(tf, widths = c(10, 42))

# drop trailing zeros (not sure if this is important)
ids <- gsub("0+$", "", ids$V1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your Question and with what I can understand is, you have your data as below :
Say in a CSV File:

```
 RowID,Name
 P040120000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000,A
 P040130000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000,B
 P040140000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000,C
 P040150000000000000000001001101210000000120000000000,D
```

You want to create a table based on first few digits, Below is my R code:

```
rm(list = ls())
FF = read.csv('/home/my/k.csv', header = TRUE);
S=substr(FF$RowID, 1, 6)
T1 <- table(S[1],as.character(FF$Name[1]))
T2 <- table(S[2],as.character(FF$Name[2]))
T3 <- table(S[3],as.character(FF$Name[3]))
T4 <- table(S[4],as.character(FF$Name[4]))
T1;T2;T3;T4;
```

You can create table using `for loop` , if you have lots of row fields.
 Hope I answered your question.